# Odoo qweb shows wrong datetime if connect through IP/Domain instead of localhost

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10, odoo-14

Strange problem in Odoo, If i connect through localhost:8069 i am getting correct time in qweb reports. But if connect through the machine IP address or through the domain, reports show incorrect time. Does anyone know what is causing the time and date changes?

Odoo ver 14.

Comment: Could you try to specify the timezone in settings > users > your user

Comment: I found the solution, user has the right timing. Since the data is fetch uusing sudo() function, it was taking the date time from odoo bot user which as archived. Changing odoo bot user fixed the problem